# Sharepoint asks for NTLM credentials for every unique URL. How do I stop it?

Tags: sharepoint, authentication, ntlm

I'm tasked with troubleshooting a problem we're having with a SP2010 site. The app is external, and there are several clients that must connect. Some clients are receiving a crazy amount of credential requests when trying to log on. It appears to ask for every unique URL (eg. every different picture, link, etc) and it won't stop. Other clients are having no problems.

I cannot seem to replicate the issue, either. I'm attempting to replicate by restricting all settings (including cookies) on my own browser, but to no avail.

I put the HTTP request under a microscope, and it's asking for NTLM credentials.

The client is using IE8, and the browser is running in Protected Mode, but the browser settings cannot be determined...

I'm guessing this is a webserver thing, simply because it appears to be an authentication thing. What might the problem be?

Answer (score 1):

If some clients do not have problems and others do then the problem should be on the client side. It's hard to tell but a couple of things you should check:

- Make sure they are running one of the level 1 Web browsers, Internet Explorer 6, 7 or 8
- Make sure they have SharePoint site in the Trusted Sites or Local Intranet zone in Internet Explorer
- Make sure Trusted Sites are configured to **Automatic Logon with Current Username**
- If you cannot add it to Trusted or Intranet zones make sure there are no warnings about ActiveX controls in Internet Explorer Warning Bar, if there are run all active X controls.

Comment: They are running IE7, with no ActiveX errors. The problem I'm finding is that even when I change all the browser settings to the most restrictive, it still works fine for me... Is there anything that putting a site into the Trusted Zone does that isn't controllable from within the browser settings?

Answer (score 0):

It could be your client's request get mangled by a proxy? HAve you tried reaching your site from the client's premises?

Comment: This isn't the case, as when the workers take their laptop home and connect (no VPN), it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

There could be an image or the like that the user does not have access to. I've had this happen with pdf document icons on SharePoint.

Comment: This isn't the case, as the same username/password from a different client site works just fine